# Algebra: operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a multiplicative identity with additive inverse of infinite multiplicative order? In all the examples I know, the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity has multiplicative order 2. For example, the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity 1 is -1 and the multiplicative order of -1 is 2. I need a counter-example involving two familiar operations, not necessarily multiplication and addition.

Comment: (1) You can prove $(-a)(-b)=ab$ in *any* ring. (2) Counterexample to what?

Comment: I need an identity say e of operation # for which the inverse in operation $ say E does not yield E#E=e. We are not necessarily in a ring. Let us think in general.

Comment: exactly, give me an example where x is an identity for multiplication, but (-x)(-x) is not 1.

Comment: @Khaled that's impossible, per anon's first comment.

Comment: Oh, are you defining E to be the inverse of e with respect to $ in your comment? @Omnomnomnom My comment was about addition and multiplication, not arbitrary operations.

Comment: yes anon, that is right.

Comment: @anon I specifically mean we can't have $(-1)(-1) \neq 1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Either your comment was responding to Khaled's comment, and Khaled's comment is talking about arbitrary operations, making your comment moot, or else your comment was responding to the original post, which would make your comment superfluous after mine.

Comment: I mean arbitrary operations. For example, the f(x)=x is an identity for composition of functions, while its inverse of addition is g(x)=-x. Moreover (gog)(x)=x.

Comment: Let us think of arbitrary operations.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I need.

Comment: this is my first use of the site. Anon are you still there?

Answer (score 1):

If you're really asking about arbitrary operations, as your comments suggest, then this is easy:

- We'll define two operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ on $\mathbb{N}$.
- Our first operation, $\otimes$, is just the usual multiplication. So the $\otimes$-identity is 1.
- Our second operation, $\oplus$, is given by setting $x\oplus 2=2\oplus x=x$ (so $2$ is the $\oplus$-identity), $1\oplus 3=3\oplus 1=2$, and - if $x, y\not=2$ and $\{x, y\}\not=\{1, 3\}$ - then $x\oplus y=7$. *This is a very stupid operation.*

Now note that $1$ has a $\oplus$-inverse, namely $3$. But clearly $3$ has infinite $\otimes$-order.

This should be a cautionary tale: practically any behavior you want can occur in *some* algebraic structure, it's usually when we ask for certain phenomena to occur *while obeying global rules* (e.g. associativity, commutativity, . . .) that things get iteresting. In particular, when you have multiple operations under consideration, they will usually be related in some way (e.g., distributivity).

Comment: This is a good example, but I need one with two operations which both exist in the literature. Not like the second operation in this example.

Comment: What do you "need" them for? (This might help me come up with a better example . . .)